# Facing an issue while learning logical ML

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

When i run my code i am facing an error

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_validate_params'
```

Here is my code:

```
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression as lr
from sklearn import metrics

lol = {"exp":[0,2,5,6,10,7,9,3,5,4,6,1,2,0,0,4,5,8,7,6],
    "sales":[10,20,15,12,14,18,19,20,25,10,5,7,8,20,15,17,18,25,14,17],
    "manage":[5,2,9,8,3,6,7,5,4,2,1,5,8,7,9,4,2,0,1,5],
    "get":[0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1]}
data = pd.DataFrame(lol,columns=["exp","sales","manage","get"])

x = data[["exp", "sales", "manage"]]
y = data["get"]

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=0)

lr.fit(x_train,y_train)
x_pred = lr.predict(x_test)

conf_mat = pd.crosstab(y_test,x_pred,rownames="True?",colnames="Pred")
sb.heatmap(conf_mat,annot=True)

print("Accuracy:" ,metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,x_pred))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Where exactly? Please update your post with the full error trace - see how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues were with how you were importing `LogisticRegression`, and the syntax for `pd.crosstab`. See below for fixes.

[image]

```py
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import metrics

data_dict = {"exp":[0,2,5,6,10,7,9,3,5,4,6,1,2,0,0,4,5,8,7,6],
    "sales":[10,20,15,12,14,18,19,20,25,10,5,7,8,20,15,17,18,25,14,17],
    "manage":[5,2,9,8,3,6,7,5,4,2,1,5,8,7,9,4,2,0,1,5],
    "get":[0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1]}
data = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

x = data[["exp", "sales", "manage"]]
y = data["get"]

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=0)

lr = LogisticRegression() #Make a new LogisticRegression instance
lr.fit(x_train,y_train)   #Fit the new instance
x_pred = lr.predict(x_test)

conf_mat = pd.crosstab(index=y_test, columns=x_pred) #rows=y, columns=predictions
ax = sb.heatmap(conf_mat,annot=True, )
ax.set_xlabel('prediction')
ax.set_ylabel('label')
print("Accuracy:" ,metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,x_pred))
plt.show()
```